# How do I use CharNext in the Windows API properly?

Tags: c++, unicode, multibyte

I have a multi-byte string containing a mixture of japanese and latin characters. I'm trying to copy parts of this string to a separate memory location. Since it's a multi-byte string, some of the characters uses one byte and other characters uses two. When copying parts of the string, I must not copy "half" japanese characters. To be able to do this properly, I need to be able to determine where in the multi-byte string characters starts and ends.

As an example, if the string contains 3 characters which requires [2 byte][2 byte][1 byte], I must copy either 2, 4 or 5 bytes to the other location and not 3, since if I were copying 3 I would copy only half the second character.

To figure out where in the multi-byte string characters starts and ends, I'm trying to use the Windows API function CharNext and CharNextExA but without luck. When I use these functions, they navigate through my string one byte at a time, rather than one character at a time. According to MSDN, CharNext is supposed to *The CharNext function retrieves a pointer to the next character in a string.*.

Here's some code to illustrate this problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string.h>

/* string consisting of six "asian" characters */
wchar_t wcsString[] = L"\u9580\u961c\u9640\u963f\u963b\u9644";

int main() 
{
   // Convert the asian string from wide char to multi-byte.
   LPSTR mbString = new char[1000];
   WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, wcsString, -1, mbString, 100,  NULL, NULL);

   // Count the number of characters in the string.
   int characterCount = 0;
   LPSTR currentCharacter = mbString;
   while (*currentCharacter)
   {
      characterCount++;

     currentCharacter = CharNextExA(CP_UTF8, currentCharacter, 0);
   }
}
```

(please ignore memory leak and failure to do error checking.)

Now, in the example above I would expect that characterCount becomes 6, since that's the number of characters in the asian string. But instead, characterCount becomes 18 because mbString contains 18 characters:

```
é–€é˜œé™€é˜¿é˜»é™„
```

I don't understand how it's supposed to work. How is CharNext supposed to know whether "é–€é" in the string is an encoded version of a Japanese character, or in fact the characters é – € and é?

Some notes:

- I've read Joels blog post about what every developer needs to know about Unicode. I may have misunderstood something in it though.
- If all I wanted to do was to count the characters, I could count the characters in the asian string directly. Keep in mind that my real goal is copying parts of the multi-byte string to a separate location. The separate location only supports multi-byte, not widechar.
- If I convert the content of mbString back to wide char using MultiByteToWideChar, I get the correct string (門阜陀阿阻附), which indicates that there's nothing wrong with mbString.

EDIT:
Apparantly the CharNext functions doesn't support UTF-8 but Microsoft forgot to document that. I threw/copiedpasted together my own routine, which I won't use and which needs improving. I'm guessing it's easily crashable.

```
  LPSTR CharMoveNext(LPSTR szString)
  {
     if (szString == 0 || *szString == 0)
        return 0;

     if ( (szString[0] & 0x80) == 0x00)
        return szString + 1;
     else if ( (szString[0] & 0xE0) == 0xC0)
        return szString + 2;
     else if ( (szString[0] & 0xF0) == 0xE0)
        return szString + 3;
     else if ( (szString[0] & 0xF8) == 0xF0)
        return szString + 4;
     else
        return szString +1;
  }
```

Comment: As you indicate, your posted code will work for valid utf-8, but it is not robust against ill-formed utf-8, such as if a null byte is encountered mid-character or just plain invalid utf-8. You may be in an environment where you are guaranteed that this won't happen but I'd go with some extra error checking.

Comment: Hey!  That test string looks strangely familiar... :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a really good explanation of what is going on here at the [Sorting it All Out blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/default.aspx): [Is CharNextExA broken?](http://www.siao2.com/2007/04/19/2190207.aspx). In short, CharNext is not designed to work with UTF8 strings.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm out of luck then. The funny thing is that when I call CharNextExA, I tell it that it should use UTF8. And the function happily moves along in the string without reporting any error and without calling SetLastError(). Also, UTF8 is included in the list of valid parameters. I would consider that 'broken'.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can determine (google and experimentation), `CharNextExA` doesn't actually work with UTF-8, only supported multibyte encodings that use shorter lead/trail byte pairs or single byte characters.

UTF-8 is a fairly regular encoding, there are a lot of libraries that will do what you want but it's also fairly easy to roll your own.

Have a look in here [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch03.pdf), particularly table 3-7 for valid sequence forms.

```
const char* NextUtf8( const char* in )
{
    if( in == NULL || *in == '\0' )
        return in;

    unsigned char uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(*in);

    if( uc < 0x80 )
    {
        return in + 1;
    }
    else if( uc < 0xc2 )
    {
         // throw error? invalid lead byte
    }
    else if( uc < 0xe0 )
    {
        // check in[1] for validity( 0x80 .. 0xBF )
        return in + 2;
    }
    else if( uc < 0xe1 )
    {
        // check in[1] for validity( 0xA0 .. 0xBF )
        // check in[2] for validity( 0x80 .. 0xBF )
        return in + 3;
    }
    else // ... etc.
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that [CharNextExA doesn't work with UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235798/how-do-i-use-charnext-in-the-windows-api-properly/1235956#1235956), you can parse it yourself.  Just skip over the characters that have 10 in the top two bits.  You can see the pattern in the definition of UTF-8: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8

```
LPSTR CharMoveNext(LPSTR szString)
{
    ++szString;
    while ((*szString & 0xc0) == 0x80)
        ++szString;
    return szString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but you may find the following tutorial helpful, I certainly did. In fact the information provided here is enough that you should be able to traverse the multi-byte string yourself with ease:

[Complete String Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/cppstringguide1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using 932 for the code page.  I don't think CP_UTF8 is a real codepage, and it may only work for WideCharToMultibyte() and back.  You can also try isleadByte(), but that requires either setting the locale correctly, or setting the default codepage correctly.  I have successfully used IsDBCSLeadByteEx(), but never with CP_UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

```
static const char *CharNextUTF8(const char *psz)
{
    // get the first char, and then move the
    // pointer to the next byte by default.
    BYTE c = (BYTE)*psz++;

    // if the highest bit of the char is set ...
    if (c & 0x80)
    {
        BYTE x = 0;

        // count the continuous bits set after the highest bit,
        // that means to calculate the count of following bytes.
        while (c & 0x40)
        {
            c <<= 1;
            x++;
        }

        // ok, there should be 'x' bytes following the first byte.
        for (BYTE i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            // if any byte is not a valid following byte...
            if ((psz[i] & 0xC0) != 0x80)
            {
                goto done;
            }
        }

        // all the following bytes are valid,
        // move the pointer to skip all.
        psz += x;
    }

done:
    return psz;
}
```